# Retornando NULL

Tags: mysql

Estou utilizando esta query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coluna1) as valores FROM arquivos WHERE coluna2 IN (21, 22)
```

Ela retorna os valores da coluna1 das linhas cuja coluna2 possui um dos valores especificados.

O problema é que, neste caso, o valor 21 não é encontrado na tabela. Então preciso returnar um NULL. Mas a query está retornando somente o valor encontrado.

Comment: A query só vai retornar os valores encontrados , para retornar um null é preciso recorrer a artifícios como union etc

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é bem isso que você precisa, mas faça um teste:

```
select group_concat(ifnull(coluna1, 'x')) as valores
  from (select 21 coluna2 
        union
        select 22
       ) tab_aux
  left join arquivos
    on arquivos.coluna2 = tab_aux.coluna2
```

Obs.: O 'x' representa o seu 'null'.

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu preciso. Mas tem um porém: os ids que uso vêm de um array dinâmico.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi: o 21 e 22 não são valores fixos, são gerados dinamicamente, isso? E são sempre 2 valores apenas?

Comment: isso mesmo: não são gerados dinamicamente. E o número de valores pode variar.

Comment: Cara, então não tem jeito, você terá que montar essa query também de forma dinâmica, por linha de código. Se quiser mostrar seu programa como está hoje quem sabe eu ou outra pessoa possa te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Cara, então vou tentar reorganizar as tabelas. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.